# I get the image reversed in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, flip

this is my code to turn a byte[] array into an image

```
unsafe
{
  //convert the UInt32[] into byte array and then assign the pointer to it
  fixed (byte* ptr = Misc.ConvertFromUInt32Array(image)) 
  {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200,64,800,
      PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb,
      new IntPtr(ptr));
    bmp.Save("test.bmp");
  }
}
```

And I get this:

[alt text http:////img11.imageshack.us/img11/4853/testacr.png](http:////img11.imageshack.us/img11/4853/testacr.png)

Where's the problem in the code,why that happens? How to flip it back to normal?

Comment: You can only have one picture... show the reversed one if you have to pick.

Comment: What's going on inside Misc.ConvertFromUInt32Array(image)? Could the problem not be occurring in there rather than the little bit of code saving the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
```

Fixed the problem :)

Comment: The hero we deserve

Answer (score 1):

Hey it looks like the two images you posted are not related in any way (besides have a similar pattern of obfuscation). Did you post the wrong files?

With regard to the issue you are seeing, I would guess you are seeing a problem with the origin of the x-y axis. Normal images and graphics APIs use a slightly weird axis where you count "down" the y axis, that is to say, the point(0, 0) is at the top left of the screen and as you increment y, you go down the screen. Therefore it seems reasonable to assume that you have made a mistake in the conversion or that the two images are using a different y axis scheme.

Comment: No,I dont think so.The problem must be in the "bmp" line,Some people said the problem is in strides(the parameter should be negative),but its not there.

Comment: Which "bmp" line are you talking about? "Stride" is on one of the lines containing "bmp"

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace all that unsafe stuff with :

```
private static Bitmap ConvertFromBytes(Byte[] imagebytes)
{
   return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imagebytes));
}
```

Comment: Because imageBytes doesn't contain the bitmap header.