# Creating a bitmap from a byte[]

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a `byte[]` which create from a stream which i need to create a **Bitmap** image

i was trying

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(btarr);
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap();
 img=img.FromStream(ms);
```

im sure that `btarr` is filled with stream bytes and valid bitmap content , but this always provide the img as `null` .. any idea?

Comment: It's usually useful to specify where the classes you are using come from, unless they come from the BCL. What Bitmap are you using? System.Drawing.Btimap does not have default constructor, so if you used it, the above would not even compile, so you can't be using this one. Also the BCL Bitmap does not have FromStream method. If the above is not a "real" example, it might help, providing a real one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this method will do the job:

```
public static Bitmap BytesToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
{
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
   {
      Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
      return img;
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the [Image.FromStream documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) states that "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image." Enclosing the MemoryStream in a using statement will cause it to be disposed and some, if not most, subsequent calls to the returned Bitmap object will throw a "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception.

Comment: As Anlo said the accepted answer is incorrect: you can't work with returned Bitmap cause it requires a live Stream object.

Answer (score 3):

As I mention in the comment it is hard to understand what Bitmap class you are working with, since one from the BCL neither has parameterless constructor nor `FromStream` method.

I tried to corrected your sample code to use BCL and this is what I got:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace SO6463811
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            byte[] btarr = new byte[] 
            { 
                0x42, 0x4D, 0x76, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC4, 0x0E, 
                0x00, 0x00, 0xC4, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
                0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 
                0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 
                0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 
                0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 
                0x01, 0x00 
            };



            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(btarr);
            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}, Height: {1}", img.Width, img.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

You can compile and run this code, and observe that it displays this output:

```
Width: 8, Height: 8
```

Thus, the code indeed is reading the bitmap and can access the bitmap's internals. In this case img (obviously) is not null.

From you problem description it is very hard to understand what's going on in your particular case, since you are not giving an example of bitmap, you are trying to load, and either you are not specifying what framework you are using, or providing an example of using default framework that does not demonstrate the behaviour you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

See if the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742236/how-to-create-a-bmp-file-from-byte-in-c) are of any help.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e57f7731-c703-4c17-b1a2-32b155f9b745/