# Convert Image to byte array and pass it to web api to save image on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to do convert image in byte array and pass it to web api to save image on server and image name in database.

I have done following code but getting exception as **Parameter is not valid** when I am using this block -

```
byte[] param contains byte array value of image from request url
     using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(param))
                    {
                        var cd= Image.FromStream(ms);
     //...
                    }

 using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(param))
                    {
                        var Image= Image.FromStream(ms);
     //...
                    }
```

I have tried the solutions as I have found in searching but same error occured.

Can anyone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Image.FromStream is to create an image from a stream

Comment: Yes I am trying to do so but it throws above mentioned exception.

Comment: check the number of bytes in param to make sure the size didn't change from source.  The method FromStream checks the image to make sure it is valid and will give an exception when the byte array doesn't contain a valid image.  Often when I'm solving issues like this I find where the size changes to find root cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what `param` really is:

1. Raw pixel data?

   You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742387/767890).
2. An image file?

   Your code should work. The error you are getting is probably due to the fact that it is not.
3. A serialized image?

   In that case, you'd need to use a `Binary` formatter. You can find one in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` namespace.

   To get an image from a `byte[]` buffer you'd do the following:

   ```
   Image deserializedImage = null;

   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes, false))
   {
       deserializedImage = (Image)formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
   }
   ```

If none of these options work, then you need to investigate how exactly is `param` generated and the data it contains.